# str_replace function in theme

Tags: functions, filters, the-content, customization

I am trying to change the color to red on certain words on my site. However the below code changes each word to "array".

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
function replace_content($content)
    {
    $newwords = array("Check", "Map", "Comments", "Send", "Print");
    $content = str_replace($newwords, '<span style="color:red">' . $newwords . '</span>', $content);
    return $content;
  }
  add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Comment: That happens, because you've put an array into the string: `'<span style="color:red">' . $newwords . '</span>'`.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to further research and I was able to get it to work with this:

Answer (score 2):

```
function replace_content($text) {
  $replace = array(
    'Check' => '<span style="color:red">Check</span>',
    'Map' => '<span style="color:red">Map</span>',
    'Comments' => '<span style="color:red">Comments</span>',
    'Print' => '<span style="color:red">Print</span>'
  );

  $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
  return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```